# C# & SQL Server : ExecuteNonQuery returning -1, when UPDATE works?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo, executenonquery

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have searched for an hour and not found the exact problem I am having.

I am using SMO to run some queries against SQL Server, because I have read this can handle `GO` statements, as opposed to `System.Data.SqlClient`.

I am running this query:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO  

UPDATE Program
SET ENABLED = '1'
WHERE Program_ID = '64' AND Program_Name = 'DoesSomething'
```

I am capturing the "rows affected" by:

```
int numberOfRows = db.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(s.Query);
```

The problem I am having is that this returns a value of -1 every time. I am checking the database behind the scenes and it DOES update the value every time, and when I manually run the query in SSMS, I receive the (1 row affected) confirmation.

After reading some other posts I have come to think the problem may be in the first four lines of this query. I removed the `GO` statements, and the query returned with a value of 1 instead of -1.

Most queries/scripts my group writes has `GO`, `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`, and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` pretty much as standard so its everywhere (another problem for another day- I'm aware it is excessive/irrelevant in this case). Is this affecting my row count somehow? If so can you provide some direction for a workaround or perhaps another route to get this result?

And yes... I am aware `ExecuteNonQuery` should return the number of rows affected. I just need to know why it is not returning what I think it should (in this case 1).

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: `Is this affecting my row count somehow?` You have proven that it is, and you have the solution. I don't know why it makes a difference, but you have said that the extra statements are `excessive/irrelevant in this case`.

Comment: `GO` is **not** a (SQL) statement - it's just a **delimiter** used by SQL Server Management Studio (and that's the reason why using "normal" SQL won't work - since `GO` really isn't a SQL statement....)

Comment: @marc_s that is why OP uses SMO which _can_ handle GO.

Comment: @DanWilson I have set this query up as a test. So in my case these statements are useless, but I'm trying to create a small program that can run them because I know for a fact these statements will need to be used on bigger queries my team builds, so that is why I am trying to run this one to iron things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GO` is a the batch seaparator used by SQLCMD, OSQL and other tools. Since SMO's [`ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199350.aspx) happens to recognize the SQLCMD commands, it handles the batch separator for you and executes every batch you issue in your text. The 'return' value of a series is not a clear command, since each batch may have its own return (not to mention that every batch may contain multiple statements). So I would take that 'return' value with a grain of salt. If you want to confirm the number of rows updated, use an OUTPUT clause in the UPDATE and have a result set, or assign `@@ROWCOUNT` to an output variable.

Comment: This clears up some stuff. Thank you for the clarity. Let me pose this question- Suppose for the sake of argument nobody adds the output clause to the end of the update statement. Can I programmatically add it to the end? If so, would there be issues with this? Asking because currently nobody writes queries with the output clauses , and it would be difficult to get this as a standard across all our teams.

Comment: No, you cannot. It has to be embedded in the statement, at the right position, and changes semantics. I would rather explore split the text into batches myself (ie. seek the `GO`s) and make sure you execute only one batch in every call. Then you can decide what 'return' means for each.

Comment: I don't undestand why your team writes queries in this way and then expects that you run them from C#. If they want to run these queries from code then they should fix the way in which they write the queries.

Comment: just FYI, long ago I wrote a library to handle `GO` and other SQLCMD commands in 'plain' C#, see https://github.com/rusanu/com.rusanu.dbutil.

Comment: @RemusRusanu awesome. That is the direction I will go. THANK YOU!